# Is the sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

> The Government granted relief payment of 5000$ each to those who injured in the fire accident.

Is there any word missing, eg. *a* relief payment, or those who *were* etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Government granted *a* relief payment of $5000 each to those who *were* injured in the fire accident.

**usage of were:**

> Were is used in the second person singular and plural (you, your,
>   yours) and first and third person plural (we, they).

The link for understanding it: [Was-vs-were difference](https://writingexplained.org/was-vs-were-difference)

Comment: In English we express currency by putting the denomination *first*; I recommend you [edit] your answer, as this error could easily attract downvotes. *Were* is obvious but you haven't explained why the *article* is necessary. There are plenty of examples in [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=granted+relief%2Cgranted+relief+payment%2Cgranted+payment&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgranted%20relief%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgranted%20payment%3B%2Cc0) of *granted relief* and *granted payment*....

Comment: Hey, I've edited my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.